# Value of variable not getting passed into the echo statement

Tags: php

I m passing the value in the href attribute by using a variable, but the value of variable is not getting passed, either it passes nothing or the variable name itself.

How do I use quotes and variables in order to pass the value of variable successfully?
Below is the code:

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++)
  {

    $html= '<a href="productTest.php?pro='".$out[$x][2]."'>'.$out[$x][0].'</a>: added on-'.date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($out[$x][1]));
    //<a href="productDisplay.php">Products</a>
    echo $html;

    echo "<br><br>";

  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++)
  {

    $html= '<a href="productTest.php?pro='.$out[$x][2].'">'.$out[$x][0].'</a>: added on-'.date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($out[$x][1]));
    //<a href="productDisplay.php">Products</a>
    echo $html;

    echo "<br><br>";

  }
  ?>
```

I replaced `'".$out[$x][2]."'` with `'.$out[$x][2].'`